# Viewing .rst within a "github pages" site

Tags: github, restructuredtext, github-pages

I'm moving an open source project's documentation over to Github Pages but I'm stuck on moving the .rst files.

We have a ReadMe.rst which you can see [here](https://github.com/pi3d/pi3d.github.com) in the code.  I'd like to link to that page from our [main documentation page](http://pi3d.github.com) but GitHub doesn't render the .rst as HTML so the browser simply downloads the text of the .rst file when you click [the link](http://pi3d.github.com/ReadMe.rst)).

There are of course tools to render .rst as HTML but that's a serious extra step.  The whole reason we started using .rst was entirely because GitHub renders it automatically in code pages.  You'd think there'd be some way to get this authomatic rendering happening for Github Pages...

Comment: Did you find anything? I am facing the same issue

Comment: No - we just gave up on it unfortunately.  :-( Do update us here if you have any results.

Comment: @TomSwirly Following your links, it looks like you have decided to use sphinx to render your README.rst files. That's exactly the solution I've chosen for [one](https://github.com/mangalam-research/wed) of my repositories. (Not implemented yet.)

Comment: @Louis-DominiqueDubeau - yes, it worked out pretty well actually.  The project is still nominally beta but is actually pretty mature and somewhat in use so I guess someone is reading that documentation...

Answer (score 5):

GitHub Pages does not have support for .rst/RestructuredText. It only supports Markdown and Textile conversion to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages does not have support for reStructuredText directly, but Anne Gentle has created a nice demo of how you can get something working with reasonably simple steps:

https://github.com/annegentle/create-demo

Especially useful to look at the github workflow for how to automatically generate the needed HTML from reStructuredText sources on every commit.